# How to bind IP address to a Spring 3 @ModelAttribute?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Here's how my method looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String create(@ModelAttribute("foo") @Valid final Foo foo,
        final BindingResult result, final Model model) {
    if (result.hasErrors())
      return form(model);
    fooService.store(foo);
    return "redirect:/foo";
}
```

So, I need to bind the IP address to the `Foo` object probably by calling `getRemoteAddr()` on `HttpServletRequest`. I've tried creating `CustomEditor` for `Foo`, but it doesn't seem to be the proper way. `@InitBinder` looks more promising but I've yet to found out how.

The IP address is mandatory on the object and Spring combined with JSR-303 bean validation will give a validation error unless it is there.

What would be the most elegant way to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `@ModelAttribute`-annotated method to prepopulate the object with IP address:

```
@ModelAttribute("foo")
public Foo getFoo(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    foo.setIp(request.getRemoteAddr());
    return foo;
}

@InitBinder("foo")
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setDisallowedFields("ip"); // Don't allow user to override the value
}
```

**EDIT:** There is a way to do it using `@InitBinder` only:

```
@InitBinder("foo")
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder, HttpServletRequest request) {
    binder.setDisallowedFields("ip"); // Don't allow user to override the value
    ((Foo) binder.getTarget()).setIp(request.getRemoteAddr());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I never saw an example like this in the Spring documentation. I chose the first way because the pure `@InitBinder` way seems somewhat clumsy with the casting.